# Having trouble installing basic packages in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install basic packages in `R` but having a lot of trouble. I've tried several solutions but am having trouble getting to the bottom of it. I've added `dependencies = TRUE`, made sure my `R` was updated, tried to manually install packages, all to no avail.

> Error message: also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘utf8’, ‘pillar’, ‘tibble’, ‘testthat’, ‘covr’

```
Warning message in install.packages("readr", dependencies = TRUE):
“installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("readr", dependencies = TRUE):
“installation of package ‘utf8’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("readr", dependencies = TRUE):
“installation of package ‘covr’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("readr", dependencies = TRUE):
“installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("readr", dependencies = TRUE):
“installation of package ‘testthat’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("readr", dependencies = TRUE):
“installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status”Warning message in install.packages("readr", dependencies = TRUE):
“installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
also installing the dependencies ‘utf8’, ‘pillar’, ‘bit’, ‘glue’, ‘purrr’, ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’, ‘bit64’, ‘covr’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘dtplyr’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘Lahman’, ‘microbenchmark’, ‘nycflights13’, ‘RMySQL’, ‘RPostgreSQL’, ‘RSQLite’, ‘testthat’
```

Comment: What package are you trying to install?

Comment: tidyverse and randomForest

Comment: Check if you have write access to where the packages are installed. Use `.libPaths()` to see the install path. Modify like this `.libPaths() <- NEWPATH` as necessary.

Comment: It might also be OS-dependent. Perhaps the output from `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()` would be helpful. (If windows, is Rtools installed and available? `Sys.getenv("PATH")` should include an Rtools directory.)